# How to implode image file names into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am uploading multiple images to my sql database but my implode method isn't working...

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $id     = $_POST['id'];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file_upload']['name']); $i++){
      $filetmp  = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $filename = basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name'][$i]);
      $filetype = $_FILES['file_upload']['type'][$i];
      $filepath = "../images/".$filename;
      move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);
    }
      $mainfiles = implode(", ", $filename);

      $sql  = "INSERT INTO pictures2 (";
      $sql .= "image, photograph_id";
      $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
      $sql .= $database->escape_character($mainfiles) ."', '";  
      $sql .= $id ."')";
      $result = $database->query($sql);
        if($result){
        $session->message('<div class="success-msg">Pictures uploaded sucessfully.</div>');
        }

}
```

Comment: From where will you fetch `photograph_id` to save into the table?

Comment: `$filename` must be __array__ to be used with `implode`.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: @Dharman i have my escape function somewhere else... that was not what i asked

Comment: @quickSwap i didnt paste that part... how do i make the implode work?

Comment: Tell me how you get `photograph_id` and you will get your answer. is it `$i` or `$id`?

Comment: And that is what worried me. You should not be escaping; you should not be putting data into SQL at all. It might very likely be the cause of your problem. I can't see what is happening inside that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$filename` should be an array. You are passing string into implode function. Do something like this.

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $id     = $_POST['id'];
    $filename= [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file_upload']['name']); $i++){
      $filetmp  = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $filename[] = basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name'][$i]);
      $filetype = $_FILES['file_upload']['type'][$i];
      $filepath = "../images/".$filename[$i];
      move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);
    }
      $mainfiles = implode(", ", $filename);

      $sql  = "INSERT INTO pictures2 (";
      $sql .= "image, photograph_id";
      $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
      $sql .= $database->escape_character($mainfiles) ."', '";  
      $sql .= $id ."')";
      $result = $database->query($sql);
        if($result){
        $session->message('<div class="success-msg">Pictures uploaded sucessfully.</div>');
        }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it didn't work bro... it says array to string conversion on $filepath.

Comment: @sam fix this line `"../images/".$filename;` and it should be fine.

Comment: @sanmexma If you found this useful please up vote the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Made changes like this, I am considering `$id` is your `photograph_id`

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file_upload']['name']); $i++) {
        $filetmp    = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $filename[] = [$id, basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name'][$i])]; // here changes
        $filetype   = $_FILES['file_upload']['type'][$i];
        $filepath   = "../images/" . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);
    }
    // I made changes at below code
    $valueStr = array_map(function ($item) {
        return "('" . implode("','", $item) . "'),"; // to convert into `,` separated values
    }, $filename);
    $mainfiles = rtrim(implode("", $valueStr), ','); // removing right training `,`

    $sql = "INSERT INTO pictures2 (";
    $sql .= "image, photograph_id";
    $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
    $sql .= $database->escape_character($mainfiles) . "', '";
    $sql .= $id . "')";
    $result = $database->query($sql);
    if ($result) {
        $session->message('<div class="success-msg">Pictures uploaded sucessfully.</div>');
    }

}
```